# Does series of $\frac{1}{n} (\frac{2}{(-1)^n - 3})^n$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} (\frac{2}{(-1)^n - 3})^n$ converge? If so, how?

I think it converges, but I don't know how to use the alternating series test here, since I can't figure out a way to write the series as $\sum (-1)^n a_n $. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is odd, the term inside parentheses becomes $(-1/2)$, and due to the exponent converges quite quickly.

If $n$ is even, however, we see that

$$\sum_{n \text{even}} \frac 1 n \left(\frac 2 {(-1)^n - 3}\right)^n = \sum_{n \text{ even}} \frac 1 n \left(-1\right)^n = \sum_{n \text{ even}} \frac 1 n$$

This series diverges by considering the harmonic series.

Comment: If n is odd, the term inside the parenthesis becomes (-1/2) doesn't it? Anyway, your reasoning still holds. The 1/n term doesn't matter in the odd case?

Comment: @akeenlogician Yes, you're right that it should have been $1/2$. In the odd case, note that the series with terms $\frac{n}{2^n}$ is absolutely convergent by comparison to $\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: So overall, this series would diverge, right? Do I need to prove this explicitly?

Comment: @akeenlogician Yes, it's divergent. As far as proving it, perhaps you have already proven or seen the result that the sum of an absolutely convergent series with a divergent one is divergent.